# UIAlertController pushes navigation bar item

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uialertcontroller

UIAlewrtController pushes the button in my navigation controller down (see image)

Sequence of execution:

1. on push + the alert controller is activated
2. on selecting "Take an Action" or "Request an Action" the view controller ActionDetialsVC is activated.
3. on showing ActionDetialsVC
4. on back the ActionDetialsVC is closed
5. The iitial controlers BACK arrow moved

When putting breakpoints on:

1. self.present (alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
2. the first Swift instruction in the 2 alert handlers

The strange navigation back button behavior is visible between these breakpoints.

The issue ONLY occurs when introducing Alert Controllers in my views !!!!!

Thank you for your help

Image of the issue: 
[image]

The code:

```
func addPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController (title: "Add an Action", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let request = UIAlertAction (title: actionType.Request.Str(), style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        action in

        self.actionTypeTemp = actionType.Request.Str()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueActionDetailsVC", sender: nil)
    }  )

    let take = UIAlertAction (title: actionType.Take.Str(), style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        action in

        self.actionTypeTemp = actionType.Take.Str()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueActionDetailsVC", sender: nil)
    }  )

    let done = UIAlertAction (title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil )

    alert.addAction(request)
    alert.addAction(take)
    alert.addAction(done)

    self.present (alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueActionDetailsVC" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ActionDetailsVC {
            if let action = sender as? PActions {
                destination.actionToEdit = action
            }
            else {
                if actionTypeTemp == actionType.Request.Str() {
                    destination.relatedContact = self.contact
                    destination.title = actionType.Request.Str()
                }
                else {
                    destination.relatedContact = self.contact
                    destination.title = actionType.Take.Str()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but I would consider using an `.actionSheet` for this implementation's `preferredStyle`. Alerts should be used for, well, alerts

Comment: I also do not believe this is the fault of the UIAlertController, but actually the implementation of the search bar on the navigation bar. Notice the the arrow seems to be centered between the top of the navigation bar and the bottom of the search bar